# how to access json object after loading it in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I loaded a json object using d3.json and assigning the loaded json file to a global variable but when I print the global variable to the console it returns undefined, but when i type in the global variable in the chrome console it returns what I need it to. Essentially, I am just looking to load the json object be able to use it outside the d3.json function. This seems like a relatively simple task but I am a js/d3 newby so any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Code is provided below

```
    <script type = "text/javascript" source='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'>

var gapminder;

d3.json("D3_jsondata.json", function(data){
  gapminder = data;
});
//above prints in console when i type in gapminder

console.log(gapminder);//prints as 'undefined' in Chrome's console
</script>
```

Comment: When do you call `console.log`, inside of callback or outside?

Comment: Data not available because async call not complete.  Instead do stuff with data inside callback func.

Comment: apologies, code got cut off. console.log(gapminder) gets called outside of the d3.json

Comment: There are two types of JavaScript programmers: ... and those who don't. Those who understand asynchronous code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling .json() gets you a promise for the body of the http response that is yet to be loaded. Try to start rendering inside the callback of the json!

Comment: The json array prints inside the d3.json function. However, once I am in the function and start trying to append the svg to the body, nothing is rendering on the screen. It appends and renders when I use dummy data outside of d3.json

Comment: @OK_Sooner: Markus' advice is correct (this answer could be better elaborated, though). If you still have issues, you have **another** problem then. That being the case, post a new question specifying it.

Answer (score 0):

For *d3.json*, *d3.csv* and *d3.tsv* are asynchronous request functions, so the **console.log()** will run before **d3.json()** where "gapminder" is still *undefined*.

After the **console.log()** then it's the term of **d3.json()** to run and you make a assignment "gapminder" with the json data, so it's not *undefined* anymore.